# Паяльник и программирование

Tags: железо

С помощью чего прокачать навыки в области создания устройств методом паяльника + программирования? Существуют книги, устройства (программаторы и т.п.) чтобы сразу испытать себя в деле?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Исключительно мое видение.

Самый простой старт в этой сфере - это, пожалуй, Arduino и клоны. Выпущено множество официальных и неофициальных устройств и плат расширений. Шьются по USB. Программируются на простом диалекте С. Попутно разбирайтесь с несложной цифровой электроникой (логика, простые датчики), разводкой и изготовлением плат по технологии лазерного утюга (ЛУТ).

Как освоитесь, если поймете. что проперло - переходите к семейству [AVR](http://www.atmel.com/products/microcontrollers/avr/) (на котором базируется Arduino) или [PIC](http://www.microchip.com/pagehandler/en-us/products/picmicrocontrollers), если вы ярый нонконформист. После ардуинки вам будет уже несложно разобраться с периферией и фичами, понять какие конкретно микроконтроллеры вам нужны. Изучите полнеценный C и Assembler. К этому времени глядишь научитесь сносно платки травить и собирать.

Как надоедят 8 бит и скудная периферия - беритесь за ARM. У семейства STM есть, например, недорогие учебно-отладочные платы [Discovery](http://www.st.com/web/en/catalog/tools/FM116/SC959/SS1532/PF250863?sc=stm32-discovery) с возможность шиться через USB.

---

Немного альтернативный вариант:

Если хочется работать сразу на уровне написания модулей ядра или ПО под Linux (на чем угодно) или не покидают идеи создания умного дома - хватайте какую-нибудь одноплатную систему (буржуйские [RaspberryPi](http://www.raspberrypi.org/) и [BeagleBoard](http://beagleboard.org/), отечественные [BlackSwift](http://www.black-swift.ru/) и [Виртурилка](http://virt2real.ru/), например). Или  если совсем быстро - возьмите "народный" TP-Link-овский роутер в ближайшем магазине и ковыряйте OpenWRT.

---

Из русскоязычных онлайн-ресурсов могу выделить `DI HALT`-овский EasyElectronics с массой полезной информации для начинающих, продолжающих и специализирующихся. Там и паяльник выбирать научат и как программатор самому собрать.

Answer (score 0):

Советую почитать книги: 
Самоучитель по микропроцессорной технике. Автор Белов А.В.
Разработка устройств на микроконтроллерах AVR. Автор Белов А.В.
Практическое программирование микроконтроллеров Atmel AVR на языке ассемблера. Автор Ревич Ю.В.

Начните читать книги, и к Вам придет понимание, что нужно для программирования микроконтроллеров.